# Python App that parses file for lines that match a format

Tags: python, python-2.x, unit-testing, regex, modules

I recently wrote some code that was dinged on not having well defined tests and poor modularity. Was hoping someone could review my code and give me pointers on how to create more well-defined tests (Which is where I might be the weakest) and secondly any tips on how I can increase modularity would help.

The code receives a csv file with data. Valid data will be in three types of string format and will return an ordered list of json string representation if the string is valid. The code consists of 3 separate files main.py, errors.py, and regexes.py. Finally I'll list my tests at the bottom. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

regexes.py:

```
import re
def get_zip():
   return r'(?P<zip_code>\d\d\d\d\d)'

def get_regex1():
   """Regex for 1st instance

   Format: Lastname, Firstname, (703)-742-0996, Blue, 10013"""
   reg = r'(?P<lastname>.+), (?P<firstname>.+),'
   reg += r'\s\((?P<area_code>\d+)\)\-(?P<central>\d+)\-'
   reg += r'(?P<line_number>\d+),'
   reg += r'\s(?P<color>.+),\s' + get_zip()
   reg += r'$'
   pattern = re.compile(reg)
   return pattern

def get_regex2():
   """Regex for 2nd instance

   Format: Firstname Lastname, Red, 11237, 703 955 0373"""
   reg = r'(?P<firstname>.+) (?P<lastname>.+),'
   reg += r'\s(?P<color>.+),\s' + get_zip() + ','
   reg += r'\s(?P<area_code>\d+) (?P<central>\d+)'
   reg += r' (?P<line_number>\d+)'
   reg += r'$'
   pattern = re.compile(reg)
   return pattern

def get_regex3():
   """Regex for 3rd instance

   Format: Firstname, Lastname, 10013, 646 111 0101, Green"""
   reg = r'(?P<firstname>.+), (?P<lastname>.+),'
   reg += r'\s' + get_zip() + ','
   reg += r'\s(?P<area_code>\d+) (?P<central>\d+)'
   reg += r' (?P<line_number>\d+), (?P<color>.+)'
   reg += r'$'
   pattern = re.compile(reg)
   return pattern

def find_dict(line, regex_list):
   """Check all regex's in list for match"""
   line = line.strip()
   for pattern in regex_list:
       m = pattern.match(line)
       if m:
           return m.groupdict()
   return None
```

errors.py:

```
class PhoneNumberException(Exception):
   """Invalid Phone Number exceptions"""
   def __init__(self,errors):
       Exception.__init__(self,
                          "Phone number passed in was: {0}".format(errors))

class FormatException(Exception):
   """Invalid Format Exceptions"""
   def __init__(self,errors):
       Exception.__init__(self,
                          """Line was formatted incorrectly,
                             Passed in line was {0}""".format(errors))
```

main.py:

```
import re
import json
import regexes
import errors
from operator import itemgetter

def is_phone_valid(phone):
   """Check if phone has proper number of digits"""
   num_string = re.sub('[^\d]', '', phone)
   if len(num_string) != 10:
       return False
   return True

def make_phone(area_code, central, line_number):
   """Make Phone number from parsed phone number"""
   return (area_code + '-' +
           central + '-' +
           line_number)


def remove_keys(in_dict):
   """Remove keys to arrange dictionary in printable format"""
   keys_to_remove =['area_code', 'central', 'line_number']
   for key in keys_to_remove:
       if key in in_dict:
           del in_dict[key]
   return in_dict


def check_line(line, regex_list):
   """All Regexes in list"""
   in_dict = regexes.find_dict(line, regex_list)
   if not in_dict:
       raise errors.FormatException(line)
   phonenumber = make_phone(in_dict['area_code'],
                            in_dict['central'],
                            in_dict['line_number'])
   in_dict['phonenumber'] = phonenumber
   if not is_phone_valid(in_dict['phonenumber']):
       raise errors.PhoneNumberException(in_dict['phonenumber'])
   return remove_keys(in_dict) # This line may be changed in future


def run_input(filename, regex_list):
   """Main Function to read files and return entries"""
   # Collect all regexes
   entry_list = []
   error_list = []
   # Open file and run through items
   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
       for i, line in enumerate(f):
           try:
               item = check_line(line, regex_list)
               entry_list.append(item)
           except (errors.FormatException, errors.PhoneNumberException):
               error_list.append(i)
           except:
               error_list.append(i)
   #all lines are processed, now sort and print
   json_dict = {}
   json_dict['entries'] = sorted(entry_list,
                                 key=itemgetter('lastname', 'firstname'))
   json_dict['errors'] = error_list
   return json.dumps(json_dict, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   all_regex = [regexes.get_regex1(), regexes.get_regex2(),
                regexes.get_regex3()]
   json_return = run_input('data.in', all_regex)
   print json_return
   with open('output.txt', 'w') as write_file:
       write_file.write(json_return)
```

Tests!:

```
import pytest
import task.regexes as regexes
import task.main as main
import task.errors as errors

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def valid_lines():
   valid = {}
   valid["line1"] = "Chandler, Kerri, (623)-668-9293, Dark Fuschia, 12312"
   valid["line2"] = "James T Murphy, green, 83880, 018 154 6474"
   valid['line3'] = "Booker T., Washington, 87360, 373 781 7380, yellow"
   return valid

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def invalid_lines():
   invalid = {}
   invalid['line1'] = "Booker T., Washington"
   invalid['line2'] = "James T Murphy, yellow, 83180, 018x154x6474"
   invalid['line3'] = "Chandler, Kerri, (623)-668-9293, pink, 123122"
   invalid['line4'] = "James T Murphy, yellow, 83880, 018-154 6474"
   return invalid


def test_regex1(valid_lines, invalid_lines):
   """Test method for regex1"""
   m = regexes.find_dict(valid_lines['line1'], [regexes.get_regex1()])
   assert m['firstname'] == 'Kerri'
   assert m['lastname'] == 'Chandler'
   assert m['zip_code'] == '12312'
   assert m['area_code'] == '623'
   assert m['central'] == '668'
   assert m['line_number'] == '9293'
   assert m['color'] == 'Dark Fuschia'
   for line in invalid_lines.values():
       m = regexes.find_dict(line, [regexes.get_regex1()])
       assert not m

def test_regex2(valid_lines, invalid_lines):
   """Test method for regex2"""
   m = regexes.find_dict(valid_lines['line2'], [regexes.get_regex2()])
   assert m['firstname'] == 'James T'
   assert m['lastname'] == 'Murphy'
   assert m['zip_code'] == '83880'
   assert m['area_code'] == '018'
   assert m['central'] == '154'
   assert m['line_number'] == '6474'
   assert m['color'] == 'green'
   for line in invalid_lines.values():
       m = regexes.find_dict(line, [regexes.get_regex2()])
       assert not m

def test_regex3(valid_lines, invalid_lines):
   """Test method for regex3"""
   m = regexes.find_dict(valid_lines['line3'], [regexes.get_regex3()])
   assert m['firstname'] == 'Booker T.'
   assert m['lastname'] == 'Washington'
   assert m['zip_code'] == '87360'
   assert m['area_code'] == '373'
   assert m['central'] == '781'
   assert m['line_number'] == '7380'
   assert m['color'] == 'yellow'
   for line in invalid_lines.values():
       m = regexes.find_dict(line, [regexes.get_regex3()])
       assert not m

def test_phone():
   """Test if Phone Number is valid"""
   phone = '123-223-1212'
   assert main.is_phone_valid(phone)
   phone = '123-123-12312'
   assert not main.is_phone_valid(phone)

def test_all_regex(valid_lines, invalid_lines):
   """Test all regexes"""
   all_regex = [regexes.get_regex1(), regexes.get_regex2(), regexes.get_regex3()]
   for line in valid_lines.values():
       m = regexes.find_dict(line, all_regex)
       assert m
   for line in invalid_lines.values():
       m = regexes.find_dict(line, all_regex)
       assert not m

def test_check_line(invalid_lines):
   """Test main function for Exceptions"""
   all_regex = [regexes.get_regex1(), regexes.get_regex2(), regexes.get_regex3()]
   for line in invalid_lines.values():
       try:
           m = main.check_line(line, all_regex)
           assert False # should never happen
       except (errors.FormatException) as e:
           assert True
   line = "Booker T., Washington, 87360, 373 781 738012, yellow"
   try:
       m = percolate.check_line(line, all_regex)
       assert False # should never happen
   except (errors.PhoneNumberException) as e:
       assert True
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get great answers.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Note, it's perfectly fine to ask if there's anything wrong with your tests - but note that reviewers are always free to address any/all aspects of your code too. Sometimes the best answers don't even have a single code block - I'd suggest you [edit] your title to better convey *what your code does*, and sound a little less like you're looking for someone to write tests for your code (which would be off-topic) - that said I'm sure you'll get insightful reviews and will learn a ton! Enjoy the ride!

Answer (score 1):

#### `is_phone_valid`

```
def is_phone_valid(phone): 
    return len(re.sub('[^\d]', '', phone)) == 10
```

You define a var to use just the line after (no need).
You esentially re-build the `not` operator with your conditions (no need).
Fixing these overcomplications gives the very straightforward function above.

(An `extract_digits` helper function would make this even clearer `len(extract_digits(phone)) == 10` almost pseudocode)

#### `make_phone`

```
def make_phone(area_code, central, line_number):
    return (area_code + '-' + central + '-' + line_number)
```

(minor) Use a single line, or even remove this function as it is crossing the border of being to trivial to stand on its own.

#### `remove_keys`

```
def remove_keys(in_dict):
    # ...
         del in_dict[key] 
    return in_dict
```

You either change the argument in place XOR you return a new value. Functions modyfying the argument in place return `None` as a convention. Using a function for its return value not knowing that it changes its argument(s) can create serious bugs.

Comment: +1 for the is_phone_valid to check_digits solution, much simpler and cleaner. For the remove_keys item, knowing that the None is the convention for modifying the argument is great to know. Thanks!